# How do I enable the on-board graphics card Acer predator G3620?

Tags: multiple-monitors, bios

I have a Acer predator G3620 with NVIDIA GFORCE 630 GT, I want to connect two monitors to the pc, but the problem is that the monitors dont have HD input.  I think to connect they to the motherboard, but for my surprise, it is disabled and I dont know how to enable it, I searched in the BIOS but I didnt found anything to enable it. The chipset is H67.

Any help will be apreciated, thanks.

Comment: The issue with enabling the on-board graphics is that you would have to disable your GForce card leaving you with lack luster performance. You could, for a few dollars, buy a cable conversion piece to hook up your laptop to a non-HD monitor.

Comment: @Wescrock Can you put your response as an answer so that tato469 can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with enabling the on-board graphics is that you would have to disable your GForce card leaving you with lack luster performance. You could, for a few dollars, buy a cable conversion piece to hook up your laptop to a non-HD monitor.